# Permission in manifest (Unity)

Tags: android, unity3d, permissions, android-manifest

Не могу найти информацию, что это такое для нескольких разрешений в манифесте андроида:

```
android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE - 
com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT
com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE
com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE
com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это различные разрешения добавленные самими производителями  в систему  сматфонов. Для андроид они не являются стандартными. Но производители добавляют их и предлагают api разработчикам. 
Например  разрешение добавленное производителем ZUK

```
    <!--for ZUK-->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>
```

это вроде разрешение для добавления цифр к значку приложения, которое , например обозначает количество непрочитанных смс. В "голом" андроиде такой возможности нет и разрешение подобное будет работать только на телефонах ZUK.

Так что  информацию про разрешения отсутствующие [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)  стоит искать у производителей смартфонов

Comment: можете подсказать почему они не удаляются через  tools:node="remove" ? Как от них избавиться.
я описываю их так android.permission.UPDATE_BADGE или нужно полностью com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что значит как от них избавиться. Откуда вы хотите их удалить? с вашего манифеста?  Я по памяти не могу вспомнить операторы используемые для слияния манифестов. Но помню, что в документации рекомендуется просто в ручную удалить, а не использовать remove. Но вы пишите, что описываете их. Поэтому не понимаю что вам нужно. То хотите удалить, то описать.

Comment: @KostyaLikhachev, описать нужно как в оригинале

Comment: их нету в манифесте главном (Assets\Plugin\Android), создаются при компиляции апк, потому и удаляю так, но они присутствуют даже так

Comment: Найдите другие манифесты. Наверно вы импортировали библиотеку как модуль и в этой библиотеке есть манифест, в нем они и присутствуют эти разрешения. А манифесты сливаются в один, как они будут выглядеть видно на вкладке Merged-Manifests, когда откроете манифест.

Comment: Но если вы подключили библиотеку, то врядли вы сможете использовать весь её функционал, удалив из нее какие то разрешения.

Comment: я добавил в свой манифест первое разрешение <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>    и хоть у голого андроид такого нет, он не ругается и нормально компилирует проект.

Comment: я использую Unity с платформой под Android, все манифесты нашел - ничего из разрешений нету, наверное из .aar тянутся. Причина удаления разрешений - проект выставляется в плей маркет, сказали слишком много разрешений для фичинга

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html   вот тут почитайте как сделать правильно слияние манифестов. Смысл  в том, чтобы в главный манифест добавить эти самые операторы  tools:node="remove" и другие. Это решит ваш вопрос

Comment: <permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"
    tools:node="remove"">

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и разъяснение.